# Django apps equivalent to Drupal's CCK and Views modules?

Tags: python, django, drupal, drupal-views, django-apps

Are there any Django apps equivalent to Drupal's Views and CCK modules?

I find Django much more flexible and logically organized than Drupal. But I think Drupal's Views and CCK modules are killer apps. They let the webmaster very rapidly to build new data models and queries through GUI without touching the code. These modules are very useful for rapid application development. Do you know any similar apps in Django?

Answer (score 4):

Django is a framework, this had been said, but if you look for functionality close to CCK, PINAX makes for python/Django, the equivalent of modules in Drupal, sort of ready to go modules, login/pass check, listing, input output, or CRUDs ect. But in no ways radio buttons and check boxes action programming. You will have to put your building blocks together and indulge some python programming. I found myself spending more time loading extra modules and themes tweaking in Drupal, than putting together a full blown site in Django, maybe because, I own many libraries wrote several times and improved over time, for cases encountered over and over. I focus only on new or cutting edge things. Both approaches are ok as long as you know what you want to go. The hard fact is that for a CMS that want to attract non programmers peoples if you want to build great sites, you have to be good in php/mysql and a good grip on css, and it kind of defeats the purpose. In France we say, "the best tool is the one you use every day". If you are frustrated with Drupal, learn Django, and in the same time needed to master Drupal, you will have a skill to write your own Drupal and others CMS, maybe. Good luck in your endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is something similar and for a good reason. Django is a framework, while Drupal is a full scale CMS. One of the powerful things about Drupal, is how it handles content. Every piece of content is a node, and it lets developers make modules that can add to a node's functionality.

Django is a great tool to, but it's strength is more the ease of development, that lets you create applications very fast. That is what it was built for after all. It would be hard to make something CCK and Views like with Django, and I don't think it would make much sense either. I find that when developing with Django, you can very quickly create most CCK and views things, withe Django models and the orm. You can't do it in a GUI, but that was never the goal of Django. The admin interface also reflects that, as it is good mainly for one thing. Handling content, CRUD style operations. I guess that is why Satchmo created their own settings system for shops.

Comment: I agree that CCK/Views should not be the goal of Django. But a 3rd party Django app should cover these use cases. They are very useful for two reasons: 1. They allow rapid application development 2. They empower webmasters who are not experienced Python/Django programmers.

Comment: @Mert: I find that Django is created for web developers more than web masters. This also reflects how Django it setup. You need to code it get a basic development installation working, while Drupal can be installed with a GUI and there even is Acquia's stack installer to get all you need on a new box with no programming knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#is-django-a-content-management-system-cms

> ...it doesn’t make much sense to compare Django to something like Drupal, because Django is something you use to create things like Drupal.

Comment: I agree. But actually my goal is not to compare Django to Drupal. I just want to find an app running on top of the Django framework having features similar to CCK/Views modules of Drupal. I believe such an app doesn't exist yet or someone would probably have pointed to it.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of flexibility that you refer to is the price you pay for CCK and Views. I've used both Drupal and Django to complete major projects. You can use Drupal as a framework too, so in my opinion the two are absolutely comparable.

Django has a way better database abstraction than Drupal, follows more modern programming paradigms like OOP, MVC etc, is more flexible, and Python is just straight up superior to PHP.

...but I still usually use Drupal if either will do. It just gets the job done with less time spent, and works and performs well. Django has nothing like Views, and Drupal's form api is just light years ahead of Django's. Creating multi step ajax forms can be done without ever touching the markup or writing a single line of javascript in Drupal, and presenting dynamic lists to the user can be achieved without even leaving your browser.

Drupal has a much greater deployment rate than Django, not just because of PHP's popularity, but because it actually does some things really well.

My time is precious, and the end user doesn't give a damn as long as my system works.